# Xib editor name in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xib

I have set a Notepad++ as a default editor for Xib's, and now i'm trying to return back to Xamarin editor, but i cant find it in a list.

By default (checked on another PC), Xib's are set to be opened with Json Editor, however in real, they should be opened by VS Xamarin Xib editor.

Any suggestions where i can find it?

[image: Default settings]

EDIT: currently i'm working on Windows laptop. 
If to open project in Xamarin Studio, it would claim that it needs Mac.
However, if to open it in Visual Studio (and to set up Mac Agent) - its possible to view and somehow edit Xibs (although its buggy as hell).

[image]

EDIT2: its name is iOS Designer. Now question is where it is located on Windows.
Some info about it: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

EDIT3: okay, i had removed all mentioning about xib from Studio settings and from registry - it still opens xibs via text editor. Probably will reinstall Studio and Xamarin tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to open your solution in Xamarin Studio and double click your XIB file. You can use MVVMCross with Visual Studio. But in order to edit XIB files, it must be done on a Mac with Xamarin Studio. Xamarin Studio actually opens up XCode and you modify the XIB file using XCode.

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31353/is-it-possible-to-re-design-a-xib-in-visual-studio

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question. That info is seems to be outdated: i was able to edit Xib in VS on Windows.

Comment: I believe that you will still need a Mac running macOS.

Comment: Yes, as i said, i have active Mac in VPN, but i can do design in VS on Windows.